# 0x exchange v3 debugging (execution reverted, more details inside)

Tags: contract-deployment, signature, decentralized-exchange, 0x, dapp-debugging

I am trying to swap the erc721 token for erc20 using the 0x protocol which I deployed on the testnet.

Using the following script to perform the swap:

```js
/**
 * Local, Data & Env imports
 * Exchange.json (from vendorArtifacts attached with this gist)
 * "@0x/contract-artifacts": "^3.15.0"
 */

const addr = require('./deployments.json')
const artifacts = require('@0x/contract-artifacts')
const vendorArtifacts = require('./vendor')
const dotenv = require('dotenv')

/**
 * 0x and ethers imports
 *
 * "ethers": "^5.4.6"
 * "@0x/contract-wrappers": "^13.17.6"
 * "@0x/subproviders": "^6.6.0"
 * "@0x/order-utils": "^10.4.28"
 */

const { providers, Wallet, ContractFactory, Contract, BigNumber } = require('ethers')
const { ContractWrappers } = require('@0x/contract-wrappers')
const { PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider, RPCSubprovider, Web3ProviderEngine } = require('@0x/subproviders')
const OrderUtils = require('@0x/order-utils')

dotenv.config()

/**
 * chainID - directly obtaining from connected provider to use relevant deployment addresses
 * providerEthers - General Ethers JSON-RPC provider to create maker and taker signer
 * wrapper - 0x ContractWrappers object
 * makerEthers - Signer object connected to maker's private key
 * takerEthers - Signer Object connected to taker's private key
 * engineMaker - RPC & maker private key provider for 0x
 * engineTaker - RPC & taker private key provider for 0x
 */

let chainId, providerEthers, wrapper
let makerEthers, takerEthers, engineMaker, engineTaker

const main = async () => {

    await init()

    const exchange = new Contract(addr[chainId].exchange, vendorArtifacts.Exchange.compilerOutput.abi, takerEthers)
    const devUtils = new Contract(addr[chainId].devUtils, artifacts.DevUtils.compilerOutput.abi, providerEthers)

    const erc20 = await deployERC20(takerEthers)
    const erc721 = await deployERC721(makerEthers)

    /**
     * approving erc20 and erc721 to their specific asset proxies
     * @notice proxies are already authorized to exchange v3 contract used above
     */
    await approveToProxies(
        erc20,
        BigNumber.from('1000000000000000000000000000'),
        erc721,
        1,
        addr[chainId]
    )

    wrapper = new ContractWrappers(engineTaker, {
        chainId: chainId
    })

    /**
     * @notice not using BigNumbers in order because will cause error when signing: "does not confront to order schema"
     */
    const order = {
        makerAddress: process.env.MAKER_FROM_ADDRESS,
        takerAddress: process.env.TAKER_FROM_ADDRESS,
        senderAddress: process.env.TAKER_FROM_ADDRESS,
        feeRecipientAddress: '0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
        makerAssetAmount: '1',
        takerAssetAmount: '10000000000000',
        makerFee: '0',
        takerFee: '0',
        expirationTimeSeconds: '1947301711',
        salt: '510',
        makerAssetData: await devUtils.encodeERC721AssetData(erc721.address, BigNumber.from(1)),
        takerAssetData: await devUtils.encodeERC20AssetData(erc20.address),
        makerFeeAssetData: '0x',
        takerFeeAssetData: '0x',
        chainId: chainId,
        exchangeAddress: addr[chainId].exchange,
    }

    const sOrder = await OrderUtils.signatureUtils.ecSignOrderAsync(engineMaker, order, process.env.MAKER_FROM_ADDRESS)

    const valid = await wrapper.exchange.isValidOrderSignature(order, sOrder.signature).callAsync({
        to: addr[chainId].exchange
    })
    if (valid === true) console.log('- Maker signed order successfully')

    const abiEncoded = await wrapper.exchange.fillOrder(order, BigNumber.from('1'), sOrder.signature).getABIEncodedTransactionData()

    const output = await exchange.executeTransaction(
        ['510', '1947301711', '2000000000', process.env.MAKER_FROM_ADDRESS, abiEncoded],
        sOrder.signature,
        {
            gasLimit: 7000000,
            gasPrice: 2000000000,
            type: 1
        }
    )
    console.log(output)
}

const init = async () => {

    engineMaker = new Web3ProviderEngine()
    engineMaker.addProvider(new PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider(process.env.MAKER_PRIVATE_KEY))
    engineMaker.addProvider(new RPCSubprovider(process.env.RPC));
    engineMaker.start();

    engineTaker = new Web3ProviderEngine()
    engineTaker.addProvider(new PrivateKeyWalletSubprovider(process.env.TAKER_PRIVATE_KEY))
    engineTaker.addProvider(new RPCSubprovider(process.env.RPC));
    engineTaker.start();

    providerEthers = new providers.JsonRpcProvider(process.env.RPC)
    chainId = await (await providerEthers.getNetwork()).chainId

    makerEthers = new Wallet(process.env.MAKER_PRIVATE_KEY, providerEthers)
    takerEthers = new Wallet(process.env.TAKER_PRIVATE_KEY, providerEthers)

    console.log('- Providers Initialized Successfully')
}

const deployERC20 = async (signer) => {
    const erc20Factory = new ContractFactory(
        artifacts.DummyERC20Token.compilerOutput.abi,
        artifacts.DummyERC20Token.compilerOutput.evm.bytecode.object,
        signer
    )
    const erc20 = await erc20Factory.deploy(
        'Test ERC20',
        'TST',
        18,
        BigNumber.from('1000000000000000000000000000')
    )
    console.log('- ERC20 deployed successfully')
    return erc20
}

const deployERC721 = async (signer) => {
    const erc721Factory = new ContractFactory(
        artifacts.DummyERC721Token.compilerOutput.abi,
        artifacts.DummyERC721Token.compilerOutput.evm.bytecode.object,
        signer
    )
    const erc721 = await erc721Factory.deploy(
        'Test ERC721',
        'TST'
    )
    await erc721.mint(signer.address, '1')
    console.log('- ERC721 deployed successfully')
    return erc721
}

const approveToProxies = async (erc20, amount, erc721, tokenId, addrs) => {
    await erc20.approve(addrs.erc20Proxy, amount)
    await erc721.approve(addrs.erc721Proxy, tokenId)
    console.log('- Approved to proxies successfully')
}

main()
```

But the transaction is getting reverted each time after using 50k gas (you can check all failed attempts here: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/address/0xAc63b037242D498483C8ad18A0A71aE56e939C22 , source code is not verified on polygonscan since it is causing trouble because of usage of abi encoder v2 experimental)

I have tried different signature mechansims for signing order (eth_sign, sign typed v3 & v4), tried officially deployed 0x v3 contracts on kovan (https://0x.org/docs/guides/0x-cheat-sheet), changing order parameters, swapping maker and taker, etc.

I have also tried to match my approach with 0x protocol's integrations test to make sure everything is correct.

Here are env & deployment files to reproduce to complete environment: https://gist.github.com/hack3r-0m/71102da691183574222fcb90241a07e8

Any help would be highly appericiated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to just fill an order but your code is attempting to do it through meta transactions, which is what `executeTransaction()` does.

To execute a fill through a meta-transaction, the taker will need to sign the meta-transaction object as well, and *that* is the signature that goes into `executeTransaction()`. `@0x/order-utils` has helpers for this as well.

To fill an order directly, the taker just has to call [`fillOrder()`](https://github.com/0xProject/0x-protocol-specification/blob/master/v3/v3-specification.md#filling-orders) on the exchange contract. You are also encoding the `fillOrder()` call for too low a taker asset fill amount. I think you mean to pass in `10000000000000`, not `1`, because anything less than `10000000000000` will round down to `0` of the maker asset, due to the exchange rate the order specifies.

Comment: thanks, understood. first maker signs, then taker signs ABI encoded data for fillOrder but can tweak parameters salt, expiration time and gasPrice or it needs to be same as a maker?

Comment: also, is there a way to verify exchange v3 contracts on etherscan based explorers? bytecode of contract matches but still it does not verify. how did 0x verified it on mainnet?

Comment: the transaction went through: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x942f5bdf988d5a2c8673811f4e23d1a908827cf452b57a5f28fcded92a69687c but the balance for maker and taker is as it is, swap didn't occur, what could be reason for it?

Comment: The taker cannot change the salt or expiration time of the order because the maker already signed it. But the taker can choose whatever salt and expiration time they want for the metatransaction object that they sign. Tbh I still feel like you want to just call `fillOrder()` directly without metatransactions. All metatransactions do is let someone who isn't the taker call `fillOrder()` on their behalf.

Comment: Verifying the contracts entirely depends on how you compiled it. If you compiled it with using our tooling, you need to verify using "Standard JSON input" and find the *input* artifact in `contracts/exchange/test/generated-artifacts/Exchange.input.json`. You might have to also remove some extraneous fields from it as well.

Comment: It does look like a `Fill` event was [emitted in the transaction](https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x942f5bdf988d5a2c8673811f4e23d1a908827cf452b57a5f28fcded92a69687c#eventlog) but it filled for `0` amount. I see from your code that you are passing in `1` for taker asset fill amount to `fillOrder()`. I think you mean `10000000000000`.

Comment: I tried with that amount, but the same issue: https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0xde2000e9c1d3a59392280fc928ecd60d436e427394989950091538f728b1f08f
also, if it was amount issue then it should have filled with 1 previously and emitted Transfer event

Comment: also, I tried debugging on tenderly, there is one delegate call from the exchange address to itself but there is no further call to asset proxies which is weird. i registered proxies on exchange and added exchange's address as authorized on proxies, am i missing anything here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129730/discussion-between-lawrence-forman-and-hack3r-0m).